TDM signals crossing
I'm working on a 2-layer PCB design and trying to do the best I can for signal integrity. I have 2 TDM lines and at a certain point they cross between each other. See image below.

Is this likely to cause too much interference? Would it be better to add a ground pour to the top layer for additional protection, as in the image below?

I know a 4-layer would be a better option, but I'm trying to save costs on this project.
Thanks,
Emerson

What's the signal frequency here? I suggest you do give four-layer some consideration, too; it's a lot cheaper than it used to be.

The frequency is 22.6MHz on MCLK and 11.3MHz on BCLK. If the results are not good enough I will consider a 4-layer. But I'm hoping to learn the best implementation here as well. Tks.


Is this likely to cause too much interference?

Depends on the drive strength of the driver and the capacitance of the circuit. Any design above 10MHz needs to minimize capacitance and watch the return currents (on the ground plane). A few nH of inductance from the vias will probably not hurt at the speeds you have, but one thing that will hurt is extra capacitance and a return current that has to cross planes and can't be adjacent (on a layer next to or below) the current carrying trace.
Will it work? I can't tell you with the info you have given. But if you build the board and it has too much capacitance it won't work so minimize that. In addition with the islands of copper you are creating floating capacitors next to your traces, remove those.

that's a great answer, thank you so much!
